# Passing real time data from model to controller (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, model-view-controller

I'm using a server which sends data to the app in real time (for example: `NewMessageRecieved`, `NewImageUploaded` etc...).

I have a few `UIViewController`s that present this data and all of them should update according to the server that was sent from the server.

I thought about creating a model class called `RealTimeManager` which will get the update from the server and will send it to all of the registered `ViewController`s.

But what is the best way to register the `ViewController`s? Using an array of delegates? Is it a good way to do it?

What do you think about my method generally? If you have a better idea instead feel free to share with me.

Thank you!

Comment: `NotificationCenter`.

Comment: @rmaddy Is it a proper way of doing this? Registering a lot of `VCs` to one `Notification`?

Comment: Your model posts a notification. Anyone that cares about it registers to be told about it.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you. I'll try it

Comment: @FS.O6 notifications works one-many so yes its's proper way of doing it in your case .Delegates won't help because they are one-one.